# How to get item ID from a dropdown lookup jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I need to grab ID from the value user selects from a dropdown box. I had this code from years back and it worked before but now it returns everything. (see print shot of the alert). All I needed is the Item ID not item id;#value (for example, 3;#Alaska(AK)

[image]

```
NWF$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = NWF$('#' + jsDDTitle);
    obj.change(function() {
        //alert('test');
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("AllStates");
        //var itemID =  (this.value).substr(0, addy.indexOf('";"')); 
        var listItem = oList.getItemById(this.value);
        clientContext.load(listItem, "LinkTitle", "Modified", "Capital");
        alert(this.value);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {        
        alert('line 3');
        document.getElementById(jsCapital).value = listItem.get_item('Capital');}, function () {        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split the value and use left part, which holds your id:

```
var listItem = oList.getItemById(this.value.split(";#")[0]);
```

Comment: WOW. worked in first try. Normally I have to back and forth few times before someone understands the issue. You so smart and thanks for being generous with your time and help. I appreciate it